Estimate impact of product placement when origin is unknown
I have general weekly sales data of several products in different stores for products that can be in many locations. The challenge is that there’s no way to track where exactly each customer picked up the product. For example a water can be placed in the main refrigerator and in a small refrigerator placed near the checkout, the goal is to say how much of the sales come from the main refrigerator and how much from the small one. I’m considering a model of time series regression like xgboost that takes as input the number of water bottles in each refrigerator and see how much the sales change varying that number but at first instance the predictions are bad and I don’t know if there is a better approach.
I can’t run real experiments in the stores.

Elaborate on how you plan to use this model: what decision would it help you make? Do you have any sources of variation? An example might be variability in fridge types across stores or within stores over time. Does the register fridge contain soda instead of water sometimes? Do fridges ever break? Do you get to see stock levels or at leaast refill times?
